# Error when trying to create PDF with Rotativa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

My goal is to allow users to print to pdf, a view.  I found a Nuget called Rotativa and followed some very basic tutorials.  In test, it worked perfectly and looked like a great answer to meet my needs.

However, I am finding that implementing it into the actual working project, is giving me errors that the simple test did not.

I have an index view that is a list.  I want users to print this list to pdf.  I have tried many different classes of Rotativa (ViewAsPDF, ActionAsPDF, GeneratePDF. . . ).  I have researched and read numerous tutorials . .but I think the problem is more related to my Model. .

Here is what I have so far

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.IndexViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<style>
#content {

}

.even {
    background-color: #dcf1b8;
}

.odd {
    background-color: #f4ffe1;
}
</style>

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<p>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "PrintAllReport")
</p>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemDescription)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OriginalDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TransType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastUpdatedBy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OpenClosed)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentStatus)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentStatusDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequsitionNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PONumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeliveryMonth)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeliveryYear)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitsOrdered)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Emergency)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeliveryUnit)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastUpdatedBy)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OpenClosed)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentStatus)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentStatusDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequsitionNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PONumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveryMonth)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveryYear)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsOrdered)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emergency)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveryUnit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TransID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

</table>
```

The View loads in the browser, with correct data from the model, properly.  But, when the user clicks the ActionLink PrintAllReport . . . I see the following error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Referencing line @foreach (var item in Model)

I believe that is telling me that the Model is empty?  But, how can that be, when it populates in the browser just fine.

Here is My Index Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var q = from tr in db.ICS_Transactions

                join un in db.ICS_Units
                on tr.DeliveryUnitID equals un.DeliveryUnitID
                join kt in db.ICS_Contacts
                on tr.Contact equals kt.LoginID
                join sp in db.ICS_Supplies on tr.SuppliesID equals sp.Supplies_ID

                orderby tr.Emergency descending, tr.TransID ascending


                select new IndexViewModel

                {
                    TransID = tr.TransID,
                    ItemDescription = sp.ItemDescription,
                    OriginalDate = tr.OriginalDate,
                    TransType = tr.TransType,
                    LastUpdatedBy = tr.LastUpdatedBy,
                    ContactName = kt.ContactName,
                    OpenClosed = tr.OpenClosed,
                    CurrentStatus = tr.CurrentStatus,
                    CurrentStatusDate = tr.CurrentStatusDate,
                    RequsitionNumber = tr.RequsitionNumber,
                    PONumber = tr.PONumber,
                    DeliveryMonth = tr.DeliveryMonth,
                    DeliveryYear = tr.DeliveryYear,
                    UnitsOrdered = tr.UnitsOrdered,
                    Emergency = tr.Emergency,
                    Comments = tr.Comments,
                    DeliveryUnit = un.DeliveryUnit,
                    PhoneNumber = un.PhoneNumber,
                    Street = un.Street,
                    City = un.City,
                    State = un.State,
                    ZipCode = un.ZipCode,
                    Building = un.Building,
                    Room = un.Room

                }
              ;

        return View(q.Where(d => d.OpenClosed == "Open").ToList());

    }
```

And here is my PrintAllReport Action

```
     public ActionResult PrintAllReport()
    {

        var model = new IndexViewModel();
        //Code to get content
        return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Index") { FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf" };

    }
```

This generates the Object Reference Error.  I am confused.  Shouldn't this work exactly as the index loaded in the browser?  What am I missing?

I have also tried it this way:

```
        public ActionResult PrintAllReport()
    {

        var report = new ActionAsPdf("Index");
        return report;

   }
```

The latter gives me an authentication error: You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I am new to MVC5 and I am confused as to why the index page loads properly, but the action PrintAllReport is failing to open in pdf.  And what I need to change to make it work properly.

Update:

After Stuard gave me some good information, I have made some changes, as follows

```
        {
        var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();
        var report = new ViewAsPdf("Index", viewModel);
        return report;
        }
```

Now, I am getting a different error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ICS20web.Models.IndexViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ICS20web.Models.IndexViewModel]'

I feel like I am close . . . but no cigar.

Comment: Use [the overload of ViewAsPdf that allows you to set the model](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/Rotativa/ViewAsPdf.cs#L46)

Comment: @stuartd - Thanks for your reply. May I ask for clarification.  Why do I need to set the model, if my view already calls the model (@model IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.IndexViewModel>).  Just trying to better understand what I need to do and why

Comment: The model gets passed to your Index view. From there, you navigate to another action. This action then calls back to the invoice view via the ViewAsPdf method.  The model doesn't get passed along automatically through these steps.

Comment: @stuartd - I am struggling.  I am fairly new to mvc5 and c# and days new to Rotativa.  I am trying to set the model in the ViewAsPdf overload, and it is telling me that the 'IndexViewModel is a type and not valid in this context'  Am I using the overload properly here?   var report = new ViewAsPdf("Index", IndexViewModel);

Comment: @stuartd - I made an update to my question, at the very end.  That will show my code and how I am doing the overload now.  I am getting a different error:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ICS20web.Models.IndexViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ICS20web.Models.IndexViewModel]'

Comment: Your view expects an `IEnumerable<IndexViewModel>` - like you pass to it in the Index action - but you're only passing a single IndexViewModel when you're trying to print to PDF..

Comment: @stuartd - Thank you for taking the time to explain, and point me in the right direction.  I got it working this morning.  I appreciate all of your time in responding.